# Proving a system is nonintegrable /not solvable with Inverse Scattering Transform

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, integrable-systems

**Question:**

1. Given a PDE, is there a general method to show that it is *not solvable* using the inverse scattering transform?
2. Specifically, for the perturbed 1D NLS or the 2D cubic NLS, where was it first shown that these equations can not be solved using *any* form of the inverse scattering transform.

**Background and details:** The cubic 1D nonlinear Schrodinger equation (NLS)
$$ iu_t + u _{xx} + |u | ^2 u = 0$$ 
and the KdV equation $$u_t -6uu_x+u_{xxx} = 0$$ are both known to be integrable, and solvable via the [inverse scattering transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_scattering_transform). So, given the initial condition $u(t=0,x)=u_0 (x)$, one can compute these constants and solve an inverse, linear, auxilary problem to find $u$ for all times $t$. For example, for the cubic 1d NLS this is the Zakharov-Shabat equations, and for the KdV it is the linear, time-independant Schrodinger equation.

The 2D cubic NLS, or almost every perturbation of the 1D case, e.g., $$iu_t +u_{xx} + |u|^2 u -\epsilon |u|^4u = 0 \, ,$$ is known to be *not* solvable using the inverse scattering transform, i.e., not integrable. I didn't find any reference that explains why, however.

Answer (score 8):

The prolongation structure method developed by Wahlquist and Estabrook is one  method to show whether or not a PDE is solvable via the inverse scattering transform. (There are others - refer Y. Kosmann-Schwarzbach, B. Grammaticos, K. M. Tamizhmani (eds.), *Integrability of Nonlinear Systems*, Lect. Notes Phys. 638 Springer-Verlag 2004.)

For example, in an appendix to their second paper (on the NLS equation - J. Math. Phys. 17 (1976) 1293-1297) Estabrook and Wahlquist analyse the KdV-like equation $u_t + u_{xxx} + f(u)\,u_x = 0$, concluding that it admits a non-trivial prolongation structure (i.e. is integrable via IST) only if $f(u) = 2\alpha + 6\beta u+12\gamma u^2$, for some constants $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$.

Dodd and Fordy *"The prolongation structures of quasi-polynomial flows"* Proc Roy. Soc. Lond. A**385** (1983) 389-429 discuss methods for dealing with a general class of equations that includes your variants of the NLS.  Applying their methods to your quoted example would show why it does not produce a non-trivial prolongation structure.

As far as I can see from the literature, perturbations of the type you describe are discussed as perturbations of the IST solution of the unperturbed equation, e.g. V. I. Karpman *"Soliton Evolution in the Presence of Perturbation"* Physica Scripta 20 (1979) 462

Edit: most, if not all of the equations in two spatial dimensions - such as the Kadomtsev–Petviashvili equation - place heavy restrictions on soliton behaviour.  They've sometimes been described as "one and a half dimensional" problems.

Comment: Thank you, that's a lot to work with. I haven't read them all, but while Karpman's paper should be relevant for the perturbed 1D NLS, I don't think it can work for the 2D NLS, as it is not a perturbation of any integrable system.

Comment: @AmirSagiv B.K. Harrison _"On Methods of Finding Bäcklund Transformations in Systems with More than Two Independent Variables"_ Nonlinear Mathematical Physics 1995, V.2, N 3–4, 201–215 discusses extensions of the Wahlquist-Estabrook method to equations with more than one spatial dimension.

Comment: Whalquist-Estanbrook method is the prolongation method?

Comment: @AmirSagiv Yes, that's right. Not to be confused with Cartan-Kuranishi prolongation.

Answer (score 1):

Another method for testing integrability is the Painleve test, see e.g. [these](https://arxiv.org/pdf/solv-int/9804003.pdf) lecture notes and references therein. It has some caveats: for example, certain changes of variables do not preserve the Painleve property. Yet another possibility for integrability testing is using higher symmetries, see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302765/how-to-use-these-higher-symmetries-and-conservation-laws/309742#309742).